# C++ Namespace Specification Redundant or Useful?

Tags: c++, coding-style, namespaces

From what I understand, function resolution occurs from inner scope to outer scope.  Therefore, in the following example, `MyNamespace::foo()` will be executed in both cases.

```
foo() {}
namespace MyNamespace
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {foo()}
}

foo() {}
namespace MyNamespace
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {MyNamespace::foo()} // redundant, or safe and expressive?
}
```

However, a scenario may occur in which you intend to call `MyNamespace::foo()`, but because you `MyNamespace::foo()` is not actually defined, a defined global `foo()` is called.

```
foo() {printf("I don't think you meant to call me...");}
namespace MyNamespace
{
    //foo() {}
    void bar() {foo()}
}
```

Therefore, is it safe and good practice to explicitly state the namespace, or is this situation not frequent enough to justify the extra verbosity?

Comment: It is safe, and mainly useful in case of possible `ambiguity` (2nd case you provide, or classes having same name but belonging to different namespaces). This "extra verbosity" is the guaranty of readability and tracability as well. For example, you'll often see `std::string`.

Comment: I don't create namespaces often enough to have a strong opinion, but I think the case you're describing is rare enough to ignore. You would need both a missing identifier and a compatible symbol with the same name defined in the same scope, and the chances of that are tiny. Using a namespace from outside gives good documentation if nothing else, but within the namespace itself I'd consider it noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For functions, I recommend avoiding namespace qualifications in general, unless needed to prevent an actual or potential ambiguity.  This is especially valuable in generic (template) code, because namespace qualification suppresses argument-dependent lookup.  Allowing the functions provided with the actual classes can lead to much better code, sometimes avoiding breakage.  For example:

```
namespace foo {
    template<typename T>
    struct Ctnr {
        Ctnr();
        Ctnr( Ctnr const & );
        Ctnr &operator=( Ctnr const & );
        ~Ctnr();
        // ...
        friend void swap( Ctnr<T> &, Ctnr<T> & ); // Does not throw.
    };
}
namespace bar {
    template<typename T>
    void exchange( T &lhs, T &rhs ) {
        std::swap( lhs, rhs );
    }

    static foo::Ctnr<string> state;
    void set_state( foo::Ctnr<string> new_state ) {
        // Calls std::swap, which may throw and corrupt state:
        exchange( state, new_state );
    }
}
```

If `bar::exchange<T>()` had been written using ADL, `bar::set_state()` would have used `foo`'s non-throwing `swap()`.  It would be better to write `exchange()` as `using std::swap; swap( lhs, rhs);`